# Sum of all $4$ Digit no. using the digit $1,2,2,3,4,5,5$,

Tags: combinatorics

The Sum of all $4$ Digit no. using the digit $1,2,2,3,4,5,5$, when repetition of digit is not allowed

My Try::

Here we are selecting $4$ Digit from a set $\{1,2,2,3,4,5,5\}$ in which we select $2$ or $5$ up to twice, each

So we will form $2$ cases::

case (I) : When $4$ Digit selected no. contain one duplicate element (Like $\{1,2,2,3,4,5\}$ or $\{1,2,3,4,5,5\}$)

case (II) : When $4$ Digit selected no. contain Two duplicate element (Like $\{2,2,3,4,5,5\}$ or $\{1,2,2,4,5,5\}$ or $\{1,2,2,3,5,5\}$)

Now I Did not understand how can i proceed after that

plz help me , Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "repetition is not allowed." Presumably, $2$ is listed twice because $2$ is allowed to occur twice, or else why list it twice?

Comment: Perhaps it is meant that you can only select an element once from the list.  That is, we can use two $2$'s, but only one $4$.

Comment: @anorton Yeah, that was my guess, but wanted clarification from OP,

Comment: Yes Thomas Andrews I means the same thing as said by anorton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we approach it for the case where there are no repeated digits. We have to use $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$. There are $5*4*3*2 = 120$ such integers. The average value of each digit is $\frac{1+2+3+4+5}{5}=3$. So this yields a sum of $120*3*1111$.

Now, we approach it for the case where there are repeated digits.
Consider the case where we use 2 2's, and 2 other distinct digits. There are $4*3*{4 \choose 2} = 72$ such numbers. The average value of each digit is $\frac{1}{2} \times 2 + \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1+3+4+5}{4} = 2.625$. Hence, the sum is $72 * 2.625 * 1111$.
Cosnider the case where we use 2 5's, and 2 other distinct digits. As before, there are 72 such numbers. The average value of each digit is $\frac{1}{2} \times 5 + \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1+2+3+4}{4} = 3.75$. Hence the sum is $72 * 3.75 * 1111$.

Finally, add the cases where we use 2 2's and 2 5's. This is similar to the previous case and left to you.

Comment: Thanks Calvin Lin.......But I did not understand the concept of average value , plz explain to me thanks

Comment: @juantheron Take the case when there are no repeated digits. What is the average value of the units digit? What percentage of the time is it 1? 2? 3? 4? 5?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, because {1,2,2,3,4,5,5}={1,2,3,4,5}, 399960.

So:

1. Take off redundant numbers.
2. Make 4 digit numbers.
3. Add up resulting 399960.

For all repetability, it's obviously way larger.